# Instance deployment: 'Dockerrun.aws.json' in your source bundle specifies an unsupported version

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying docker-compose on Elastic Beanstalk. Plateform: Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.1.2

My application is a multi container stack it relies on environment variables.
I deployed a zip file containing. I also tried to find multicontainer platform but there isnt any :) I thing the platforms are updated and i can only find two docker compatible platforms on EBS.

```
lu-ebs
    .ebextensions
        environment.config
    Dockerrun.aws.json
    docker-compose.yml
```

```
ls -la
drwx------@  6      192 12 Jan 16:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  10      320 12 Jan 16:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3       96 12 Jan 13:52 .ebextensions
-rwxr-xr-x@  1     4261 12 Jan 15:40 Dockerrun.aws.json
-rwxr-xr-x   1     2004 12 Jan 13:52 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r--@  1     3003 12 Jan 16:22 lu-ebs.zip
```

`zipinfo lu-ebs.zip`

```
Archive:  lu-ebs.zip
Zip file size: 3003 bytes, number of entries: 4
-rwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx     4261 tx defN 24-Jan-12 15:40 Dockerrun.aws.json
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 24-Jan-12 13:52 .ebextensions/
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx     6488 tx defN 24-Jan-12 13:15 .ebextensions/environment.config
-rwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx     2004 tx defN 24-Jan-12 13:52 docker-compose.yml
4 files, 12753 bytes uncompressed, 2305 bytes compressed:  81.9%
```

after deploying it to ebs i am getting this error:

> Instance deployment: 'Dockerrun.aws.json' in your source bundle specifies an unsupported version. Elastic Beanstalk only supports version 1 for non compose app and version 3 for compose app. The deployment failed.

I want to deploy this app to ebs.